# Django Channels AsyncHTTPConsumer example

Tags: django, django-channels

Title says it all.
For the love of god, is there an example where there are routes both for 'http' and 'websocket' protocols?

I'm simply trying to have (along with classic django channels websockets) an async download,
and setup my asgi configuration for it,
but I can't find any examples on the internet, let alone the documentation,
how to have them both.

It shouldn't be much of an ask, but it seems that it is.